# How to use local IDE on Xdebug for remote calls

Tags: php, xdebug

My scenario:

My local machine is running PHP with Xdebug, along with my IDE.  It is accessible from the internet on port 80 and 443.

A remote API is calling the URL I give it.

I want to give the remote API the address of `http://myaddr/callback.php?XDEBUG_SESSION=foo` and have my local IDE debug this request.

There doesn't seem to be a need to have both the caller and the debug server be the same, but how do I configure this in Xdebug?

**Current settings**

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.idekey=foo
```

Comment: You're IDE is .... notepad? vi?

Comment: Do you have XDebug set up properly for "remote" debugging on your local machine, without the added complexity of the external API call? Does it work?

Comment: I am using Netbeans and debug is working fine for local debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake:

I needed to start the session with `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` so I have to give the API `http://myaddr/callback.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=foo`

`XDEBUG_SESSION` is for when the session is already started.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but you could try to remove `xdebug.remote_host=localhost` and set `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`.

(This has security implications, though, because access to XDebug is no longer limited to localhost.)

Comment: No, see http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back _If enabled, the xdebug.remote_host setting is ignored and Xdebug will try to connect to the client that made the HTTP request._ I don't want the (remote) caller to debug, I want my local to debug